# placement of multiple div (on bottom) having different height

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve bar graph for a simple html page using my own css. I am in the initial stage of creating html and css. Below is my html and css.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ismailvtl/GJUmq/

I want my **"bar"** to stay on **"line"** even if I change the height of **"bar"**.

HTML:

```
<div class="bar-holder">
<div class="bar car"></div>
<div class="bar fat"></div>
<div class="bar iron"></div>
</div>
<div class="line"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.bar-holder
{
height:auto;
width:100%;
float:left;  
}
.line {
width:100%;
height:3px;
background:#000;
float:left;
position:relative;
}
.bar {
height:350px;
width:40px;
float:left;
margin-left:20px;
border:1px solid #dedede;
bottom:0;
}
.car {
background:blue;
height:240px;
}
.fat {
background:red;
height:300px;
}
.iron {
background:black;
height:330px
}
```

Comment: I want my "bar" to stay on "line" even if I change the height of "bar". I dont get it

Comment: i have multiple bar classes , if i change the height it should stay in  on bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kiwqE

All your bars need to be absolute and have a bottom 0

Comment: Thanks a lot @Stephen, Worked.